# imageView appears bigger than it should be

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

can anyone tell me why although all the images i ahve in the `drawable` folder are of the same size, only the second image appears bigger?

below are the image and the code.

***Image***
[image]

***code***:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tableLayout_1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="@dimen/padding_all"
android:weightSum="4">

<!-- First row -->
<TableRow 
    android:id="@+id/tableRow_1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_left"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="5">
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/iv_speed"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:contentDescription="@string/speed"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_speed"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_speed_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margine_start"
        android:text="@string/speed"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv_speed_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margine_start"
        android:text="@string/empty"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>
</TableRow>

<!-- second row -->
<TableRow 
    android:id="@+id/tableRow_2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_left"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_pedal"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/pedal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_pedal" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv_pedal_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margine_start"
        android:text="@string/pedal"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <com.example.mqtt_designlayout_00.PedalView
        android:id="@+id/pedalView"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>
</TableRow>

<!-- Third row -->
<TableRow 
    android:id="@+id/tableRow_3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_left"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="5">
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/iv_gear"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:contentDescription="@string/gear"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_gear"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv_gear_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margine_start"
        android:text="@string/gear"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <include
        android:id="@+id/gearView"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        layout="@layout/gear_display"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>
</TableRow>

<!-- Fourth row -->
<TableRow 
    android:id="@+id/tableRow_4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_left"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="5">
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/iv_money"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|start"
        android:contentDescription="@string/gear"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_money"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv_money_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margine_start"
        android:text="@string/money"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <include
        android:id="@+id/gearMoney"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        layout="@layout/money_display"/> 
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see an error in second table row of your XML code:

```
<com.example.mqtt_designlayout_00.PedalView
        android:id="@+id/pedalView"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>
```

I think every XML layout element should define its layout_width and layout_height, isn't that the problem?

According to your XML, I think you want to add

```
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
```

to your PedalView element. :-)